# Как найти дни с пропуском данных в таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle

Существует таблица, в которой каждый день автоматически записываются данные.
Таблица содержит столбец `INSERT_DATE` с типом `DATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON A
ORDER BY INSERT_DATE DESC
```

В один день произошла ошибка, в связи с которой, в таблицу не записывались данные. Необходимо выяснить, в какой день это произошло, т.е. хочу найти все пропущенные дни с 1/22/2021 до сегодняшнего дня.

Comment: Вы логи смотрели?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper нет , как это посмотреть?

Comment: _Необходимо выяснить когда это произошло_, но вы же уже выяснили, это произошло 3/6/2021. В чём смысл вашего вопроса?

Comment: @0xdb ЭТО ПРОСТО ПРИМЕР

Comment: в таблице примерно 100000 записей

Comment: @RomanKonoval ДА, с 1/22/2021 до сегодняшнего дня

Comment: Какой тип у столбца `INSERT_DATE`?

Comment: @andreymal Date

Comment: @0xdb, по-моему, это классический вопрос о поиске пропусков (дырок) в последовательности ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да, классика с кол-вом решений чуть меньше, чем звёзд на небе :)

Comment: @0xdb, это точно! Мне первым пришло на ум решение с использованием функции `lag()` или `lead()` ... При достаточном количестве ответов можно будет ссылаться на этот вопрос в будущем и закрывать похожие вопросы как дубликаты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим, есть такие данные:

```
create table tab (inserted) as
    select date'2021-01-01'+(rownum-1+0.5) 
    from dual connect by level<=31
/
delete from tab where trunc (inserted) in (date'2021-01-06', date'2021-01-28') 
/
2 rows deleted.
```

То есть, за январь два дня были ошибки.

Простое решение, составить последовательность дней за данный период, и проверять - были ли записи за каждый день в последовательности. Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
with dayseq (day) as (
    select daystart+level from (
        select min (trunc (inserted)) daystart, max (trunc (inserted)) dayend
        from tab) connect by daystart+level < dayend 
)
select day daywithoutrecords 
from dayseq seq
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tab   
    where trunc (tab.inserted) = seq.day
)
order by 1
/

DAYWITHOUTRECORDS
-------------------
2021-01-06 00:00:00
2021-01-28 00:00:00
```